# PDO bindParam breaking mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a mySQL statement that goes like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `events_table`
WHERE `event_category` NOT IN (:category_ids)
```

I use bindParam to bind the $category_ids to :category_ids.

category_id is a series of comma delineated numbers, e.g. 1, 2, 8

However, once executed the statement becomes

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `event_category` NOT IN ('1,2,8')
```

These quotes around the numbers break the NOT IN function.

Is there a way to use bindParam without these quotes being inserted? Is it secure to simply write

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `event_category` NOT IN ($category_ids)
```

Comment: I didn't think to look for IN (), I was so fixed on NOT IN(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you might use this

```
   $category_ids     = array(1, 2, 8);
   $inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($category_ids), '?'));

   $db = new PDO(...);
   $stmt = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM table
      WHERE `event_category` IN (' . $inQuery . ')'
   );

   // bindvalue is 1-indexed, so $k+1
   foreach ($category_ids as $k => $id)
    $stmt->bindValue(($k+1), $id);

   $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: you got this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition?
I was hoping I was missing a proper pdo way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
$sth->bindParam(':category_ids', $category_ids, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: As soon as there is a , in the list, bindParam seems to put quotes around it. For example, if there's just one number in the list, it translates as NOT IN (8).